# Fileevent executed before proc finishes

Tags: tcl

i have the following code ...

```
lassign [ chan pipe ] chan chanW
fileevent $chan readable [ list echo $chan ]

proc echo { chan } {
     ...
}

proc exec { var1 var2 } {
     ....

     puts $chanW "Some output"
     ....

}
```

Now according to man fileevent will be executed when the programs idles
is it possible to forse fileevent to be executed before that. For instance is it possible to force the fileevent to be executed immediately after the channel becomes readable, to somehow give it priority  .... without using threads :)

Comment: It sounds like you want an asynchronous mechanism to execute synchronously. It can be done, but are you sure that is what you need?

Comment: yes, learning tcl, so im just trying different stuff, found a way to do this by putting "update" after puts , is there a better way?

Comment: Another way to synchronize is by `vwait`. I was thinking that maybe you had a problem that needed a better solution, but if you're experimenting just go where the muse leads you and good luck. (Maybe you shouldn't clobber the builtin command `exec` with your own procedure, though.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tcl never executes an event handler at “unexpected” points; it only runs them at points where it is asked to do so explicitly or, in some configurations (such as inside `wish`) when it is doing nothing else. You can introduce an explicit wait for events via two commands:

- `update`
- `vwait`

The `update` command clears down the current event queue, but *does not wait* for incoming events (strictly, it does an OS-level wait of length zero). The `vwait` command will also allow true waiting to happen, waiting until a named Tcl global variable has been written to. (It uses a C-level variable trace to do this, BTW.) Doing either of these will let your code process events before returning. Note that there are a number of other wrappers around this functionality; the `geturl` command in the http package (in “synchronous” mode) and the `tkwait` command in the Tk package both do this.

The complication? It's very easy to make your code reenter itself by accident while running the event loop. This can easily end up with you making lots of nested event loop calls, running you out of stack space; don't do that. Instead, prepare for reentrancy issues (a global variable check is on of the easiest approaches to do that) so that you don't nest event loops.

Alternatively, if you're using Tcl 8.6 you can switch your code around to use coroutines. They let you stop the current procedure evaluation and return to the main event loop to wait for a future event before starting execution again: you end up with code that returns at the expected time, but which was suspended for a while first. If you want more information about this approach, please ask another separate question here.